# Не получается опубликовать проект на github

Tags: github, github-pages

Всем привет, друзья!
Возник вопрос по публикации нескольких проектов, выложенных на GitHub. В общем у меня есть репозиторий My-Projects https://github.com/WaleriaQA/My-projects в котором по папкам распределены разные проекты. Мне бы хотелось каждый из проектов сделать видимым для других людей. Посмотрела обучающие ролики и несколько раз пробовала сделать через Settings-Pages- Main-Root-Save. В итоге появляется невалидная ссылка https://waleriaqa.github.io/My-projects/ где написано

> For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Но дело в том, что такой файл содержится в каждой папке каждого проекта. Вопрос такой- как именно я могу опубликовать каждую папку с проектом по отдельности именно через сайт https://github.com/? Неужели под каждый проект надо создавать свой репозиторий?

Comment: Ну вот же работают ваши подпапки: https://waleriaqa.github.io/My-projects/Background%20changer/ . Если нужно чтобы по https://waleriaqa.github.io/My-projects открывался список этих вложенных проектов, то нужно создать index.html со списком. Если нужно чтобы была ссылка вида `https://waleriaqa.github.io/Background%20changer/`, то придется репозиторий переименовать из My-projects в waleriaqa.github.io

Comment: insolor, большое вам спасибо за помощь. Да, действительно ссылка waleriaqa.github.io/My-projects/Background%20changer работает. Но хотела бы спросить, где вы ее нашли именно в таком виде? Или это самой надо брать первую часть https://waleriaqa.github.io/My-projects/ и вручную подставлять потом другую часть с проектом, например /Movie%20app?

Comment: Вручную добавил в адрес `Background changer` (через пробел), перешел по этой ссылке, браузер сам заменил на %20